# How to do operations on strings in array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, hash

I have this array of hashes:

```rb
array = [{:ID=>"AAA", :Quantity=>1}, {:ID=>"BBB@ST050", :Quantity=>2}]
```

If the `:ID` key doesn't have the "@" character then I add the new key/value pair `:Stage => "Finished`, otherwise the stage is the number after the characters "@ST", `:Stage => "050`. This is what I would like to obtain.

```rb
# => [{:ID=>"AAA", :Stage=>"Finished", :Quantity=>1}, {:ID=>"BBB", :Stage=>"050", :Quantity=>2}]
```

What can I do?

This is my foolish (but still working) code that relies only on `Array` operations but the initial array is different. I'm searching for a smart solution starting from the array of hashes.

```rb
array=[["AAA", "1"], ["BBB@ST050", "2"]]

for n in 0...array.length

  #######################################################################################
  if array[n][0].include?("@") == true
    array[n].insert(1, array[n][0].byteslice((array[n][0].length-3)..array[n][0].length))
    array[n][0]=array[n][0].byteslice(0...(array[n][0].length-6))
  else
    array[n].insert(1, "Finished")
  end
  #######################################################################################

  for i in 0...array[n].length

    # create couple of array
    array[n][i]=array[n][i].split
  end
  array[n][2][0]=array[n][2][0].to_i

  # insert the key
  array[n][0].insert(0, :ID)
  array[n][1].insert(0, :Stage)
  array[n][2].insert(0, :Quantity)

  # transform inside array into hash
  array[n]=array[n].to_h
end

# => [{:ID=>"AAA", :Stage=>"Finished", :Quantity=>1}, {:ID=>"BBB", :Stage=>"050", :Quantity=>2}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate over the array of hashes with `#map`, modifying the hash if needed to add the expected key/value pair, or using a regular expression I can extract the needed info and set up the value for the `:Stage` key appropriately. Using `#map!` instead modifies the existing array.

```
array = [{:ID=>"AAA", :Quantity=>1}, {:ID=>"BBB@ST050", :Quantity=>2}]

array.map! do |h| 
  if h[:ID] !~ /@/
    h[:Stage] = "Finished"
  else
    h[:Stage] = h[:ID][/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/]
  end

  h
end
```

This is one place you might want to use the ternary operator.

```
array.map! { |h| h[:Stage] = h[:ID] !~ /@/ ? "Finished" : h[:ID][/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/]; h }
```

As noted in comments, since we're modifying the hashes, but not replacing them, `#each` will also work.

```
array.each { |h| h[:Stage] = h[:ID] !~ /@/ ? "Finished" : h[:ID][/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/] }
```

As requested, an explanation of `h[:ID][/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/]`:

`h[:ID]` is accessing the value in the hash associated with the key `:ID`. `/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/` is a regular expession. It's looking for any three digits (`\d{3}`) that follow `@ST`.

By feeding this regular expression to the [`#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method on the string we get from `h[:ID]` we get the matching text. In the example, this is `"050"`.

Comment: Thank you! Some questions: why do you repeat twice the condition `if h[:ID] !~ /@/` ? Second, could you explain to me what `[/(?<=@ST)\d{3}/]` exactly does?

Comment: Editing mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You're not actually changing which hashes are included in the array, so `each` is sufficient and `map!` is not needed.

Comment: Consider writing that `def mod(array); array.each { |h| h[:Stage] = h[:ID].include?('@') ? h[:ID][/(?<=@ST)\d+/] : "Finished" }; end`. Then `mod(array) #=> [{:ID=>"AAA", :Quantity=>1, :Stage=>"Finished"}, {:ID=>"BBB@ST050", :Quantity=>2, :Stage=>"050"}]`. Notice that by using @David's suggestion of using `each`, `array` is not needed as the last line of `mod`; that is, `mod` returns the new value of `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array through an each method, I use scan method and two joins, so you can extract all the numbers after the @ in your :Id value.
Here is my code.

```
array.each do |hash|
  if !hash[:ID].match?(/@/)
    hash[:Stage] = "Finished"
  else
    hash[:Stage] = hash[:ID].scan(/@\w+/).join('').scan(/\d/).join('')
  end
end
```

I hope it can be helpful to you.